# Loading a drawable from a file stream causing an OutOfMemory error

Tags: android

I'm aware that the line

`Drawable.createFromStream(fileInputStream, "src");`

is capable of throwing an OutOfMemory error when the app's memory limit has been reached. However, I'd like to think I've been very diligent when it comes to being efficient with memory.

Here is the the block which actually retrieves the drawable:

```
if(file.exists()) {

    //Get image from app files, null if it doesn't exist
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
        drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(fis, "src");
        fis.close();

        if(!saveInCache)
            mInstanceCache.put(urlString, drawable);

        return drawable;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have never been able to reproduce the OutOfMemory exception on my end, but I get 2-3 reports a day from users who do run into it. I'd like to make my code more efficient, but I'm out of ideas. I already do the following:

1) Add small images (listview sized) to a cache which is cleared as soon as you leave that listview.

2) Always clear the ImageView's drawable and run garbage collection whenever an image is either replaced with a new one, or onStop() of the activity hosting the large image is called.

I thought that would be enough, but I guess not. One thing I thought of doing was switching to Bitmaps instead of drawables (using Android's own BitmapFactory). Would that even make a difference in terms of memory/efficiency?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the drawable from a Bitmap, using the inPurgeable option from BitmapFactory.Options. I remember having the same issue, and solved it that way.

Comment: Will try this. Thanks! I won't be able to see results right away, but hopefully I can confirm this works so others can use this in a few weeks when I see that I don't get any more OutOfMemoryErrors.

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options); 
bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);`


This is what I'm trying out now. It works, but because you're going to have both a BitmapDrawable and Bitmap in memory, wouldn't that use more memory? I don't know, maybe not. Thoughts?

Comment: If you lose the reference to your bitmap object, it will not consume memory. Remember to activate the inPurgeable option!

Comment: Yes, the `options` object in that code I posted in the comment has inPurgeable set to true. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The image should be big thats why phones that have low ram give OutOfMemory Exception.
Try to reduce the size and resolution of the image if you can. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I read that tutorial, but unfortunately it doesn't really apply to me in this case. The images I'm loading are large (around 500x500 px or so, but normally just in the neighborhood of 100kb or less. Also, I'm loading the image at it's full resolution (its a large image that takes up about half the screen, so inSampling would just defeat the purpose of having the large image, really. That tutorial mostly covers turning big images into thumbs efficiently, is there something else in there I am missing that is applicable to loading large images at their full size?